# How to join 2 tables and get the result as on object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to join two tables with SQLalchemey.

```
class Transaction(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'transaction'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    bookedBy = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    product = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('product.name'))
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP(6))


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255), primary_key=True)
    givenName = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    familyName = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    birthday = db.Column(db.Date)
```

In SQL my Code was like this

```
 SELECT * FROM transaction JOIN user u on transaction.bookedBy = u.id
```

As result I get as i expected a table where both tables are joined.
In Python i tried it with this:

```
db.session.query(transaction_db.Transaction, user_db.User).join(user_db.User, transaction_db.Transaction.bookedBy == user_db.User.id).all()
```

The result was like this:

```
[(<Transaction 37>, <User 1>), (<Transaction 38>, <User 2>), (<Transaction 39>, <User 1>), (<Transaction 40>, <User 1>), (<Transaction 41>, <User 1>), (<Transaction 42>, <User 1>), (<Transaction 43>, <User 2>), (<Transaction 44>, <User 1>)]
```

The result was right, but i want to have not tuples, rather one object where the joined is inside. Something like that:

```
[<Transaction 37 with User 1>, <Transaction 38 with User 2>, ...]
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for eager loading: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#relationship-loading-with-loader-options
That way you can query transactions and can access the user from there. You will need to add a `relationship` to `Transaction` though: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship

Comment: @Wolph that was the right way! Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after @Wolph give me a tip. 
I modified my database models to this:

```
class Transaction(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'transaction'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    booked_by_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    product_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP(6))

    user = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[user_id])
    booked_by = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[booked_by_id])
    product = db.relationship('Product', foreign_keys=[product_id])


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255), primary_key=True)
    givenName = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    familyName = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    birthday = db.Column(db.Date)
```

and my python query is now this:

```
db.session.query(transaction_db.Transaction).options(db.lazyload('booked_by').all()
```

Now i get the Transaction Object with an User Object inside.

Parsed in Json it look like that:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "user_id": "string",
    "booked_by_id": "string",
    "booked_by": [
      {
        "id": "string",
        "givenName": "string",
        "familyName": "string",
        "birthday": "string"
      }
    ],
    "product_id": "string",
    "amount": 0,
    "price": 0,
    "timestamp": "2019-08-19T11:54:20.572Z"
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the desired output you specified, it looks like you just want a list of the transactions as opposed to the list of tuples. You can do this in many ways, the simplest being list comprehension.

Take a look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-list-of-tuples-into-list/

Comment: Thanks for this idea, this way work, but i must iterate over each item, its not very efficient, if i have many transactions